# Equality of integrals with non-negative functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu$ be a measure on the usual Borel sigma-algebra defined as
$$\mu(A):=\int_A f\ d\lambda$$
where $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure and $f$ is a non-negative measurable function. Now I want to show that for all non-negative functions $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ we have that
$$\int g d\mu=\int f \cdot g\ d\lambda.$$

**Attempt** Suppose for $(a_i)_{i\in I}\subset\mathbb{R}$ we have $g=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}a_{i}\mathbb{1}_{B_i}$ ( where $\mathbb{1}_{B_i}$ is the indicator function) with $B_i\in\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then $$\int g\ d\mu=\int \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}a_{i}\mathbb{1}_{B_i}\ d\mu=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}a_{i}\mu(B_i),$$ but I really have no idea what I'm doing. Any suggestions and help is welcome.

Comment: Defined like that $\mu$ cannot be recognized as a measure (unless $f=0$ a.e.). You probably mean $\mu(A)=\int_Afd\lambda$

Comment: @drhab Yes! Mistake there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you regard $A$ appearing in the definition of $\mu$ as a fixed set. But it means a generic measurable set and the proper definition would be
$$
\mu(A) = \int_A fd\lambda, \quad\forall A\in\mathcal{B}.
$$ Let us evaluate $\int gd\mu$ for simple $g = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i 1_{B_i}$. We have that
$$
\int gd\mu = \int \sum_{i=1}^n a_i 1_{B_i}d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mu(B_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\int_{B_i} fd\lambda.
$$ But we may write $\int_{B_i}fd\lambda = \int 1_{B_i}fd\lambda$. Hence we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\int 1_{B_i}fd\lambda = \int \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i 1_{B_i}\right)fd\lambda = \int g\cdot fd\lambda.
$$ So, it is clear that $\cdot$ is a product. We've shown
$$
\int gd\mu = \int g\cdot fd\lambda
$$ for any simple function $g$. If $g$ is a non-negative measurable function, then there is a non-decreasing sequence of non-negative simple functions converging to $g$. Monotone convergence theorem now implies that it is also true for any measurable $g\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The (usual) procedure is:

(Identify "map" here as "measurable function")

- First prove it for indicator maps $g=\mathsf1_B$.
- Then prove it for nonnegative simple maps $g=\sum_{i=1}^nr_i\mathbf1_{B_i}$. Using that integrals are linear: $\int (ah+bk)=a\int h+b\int k$ where $a,b$ are constant.
- Then prove it for nonnegative maps. Using that $\int g=\sup\{\int h\mid h\text{ simple map with }h\leq g\}$
- Then prove it for maps. Using that $\int g=\int g^+-\int g^-$

First give it a try yourself.

Comment: Yes, I know about the procedure; that's why I began with an indicator function at first and then a simple function. I just couldn't do it for both. The last point isn't necessary, I think, for $g$ is non-negative.

Comment: $\int\mathbf{1}_{B}d\mu=\mu\left(B\right)=\int_{B}fd\lambda=\int\mathbf{1}_{B}fd\lambda$ and $\int\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_{i}\mathbf{1}_{B_{i}}d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_{i}\int\mathbf{1}_{B_{i}}d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_{i}\int\mathbf{1}_{B_{i}}fd\lambda=\int\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_{i}\mathbf{1}_{B_{i}}fd\lambda=$